# How to optimize this Flutter code so it does less work?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, refactoring, counter

My application is doing too much work. How can I optimize this code? I don't know how to change it and still get the same effect out of it!
I need every variable to be saved on the phone so I can always get back to that state.

I was trying to save each day score on its own variable because I don't know how to get back to it on a different way.

I'm a beginner as you can see.

The code:

```
_loadDay() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _day = (prefs.getInt('day') ?? 0);
      day = _day -1;
      _score=_counter[day];
    });
  }
  _loadCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      if(_day==1){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter1') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==2){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter2') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==3){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter3') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==4){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter4') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==5){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter5') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==6){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter6') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }if(_day==7){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter7') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==8){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter8') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==9){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter9') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==10){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter10') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==11){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter11') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==12){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter12') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }if(_day==13){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter13') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==14){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter14') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==15){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter15') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==16){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter16') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==17){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter17') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==18){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter18') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==19){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter19') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==20){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter20') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==21){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter21') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==22){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter22') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==23){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter23') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==24){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter24') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==25){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter25') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==26){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter26') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==27){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter27') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==28){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter28') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==29){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter29') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==30){
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter30') ?? 0);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
    });
  }
//Incrementing counter after click
  _incrementCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      if(_day==1){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter1') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter1', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==2){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter2') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter2', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==3){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter3') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter3', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==4){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter4') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter4', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==5){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter5') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter5', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==6){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter6') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter6', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==7){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter7') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter7', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==8){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter8') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter8', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==9){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter9') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter9', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==10){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter10') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter10', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==11){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter11') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter11', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==12){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter12') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter12', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==13){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter13') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter13', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==14){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter14') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter14', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==15){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter15') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter15', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==16){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter16') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter16', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==17){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter17') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter17', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==18){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter18') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter18', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==19){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter19') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter19', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==20){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter20') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter20', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==21){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter21') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter21', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==22){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter22') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter22', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==23){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter23') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter23', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==24){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter24') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter24', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==25){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter25') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter25', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==26){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter26') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter26', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==27){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter27') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter27', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==28){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter28') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter28', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==29){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter29') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter29', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
      if(_day==30){
        _loadCounter();
        _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter30') ?? 0) + 1;
        prefs.setInt('counter30', _counter[day]);
        _score=_counter[day];
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Loop, create the pref name via string interpolation, done?

Comment: If you have working code that you want to have peer reviewed for improvements, you should ask on [codereview.se], which was created specifically for that purpose.

Comment: @KenWhite okay thank you, I will try it there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be able to optimize the `_loadCounter` method like this:

```dart
  _loadCounter() async {
    if (_day > 0 && _day < 31) {
      final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final value = prefs.getInt('counter$_day') ?? 0;
      setState(() {
        _counter[day] = value;
        _score = value;
      });
    }
  }
```

and you could do something similar to `_incrementCounter`.

One thing I noticed is you're doing +1 and -1 between `day` and `_day`; do you need both of these? If not you might be able to use the same value. As a name suggestion, I would use `dayIndex` rather than `day`.

Second note, storing and retrieving values from `SharedPreferences` isn't very fast. You might want to look into using the `Hive` package instead.

Comment: thank you so much! It worked for the _loadCounter part!
I feel like i kind of messed it up trying it on my own with the increment counter..
I have to day variables because im showing the day on the screen.. if I would use the same variable the showing day would start with 0 I thought...

Answer (score 0):

To make your code a little cleaner start by, utilizing the String interpolation that Dart provides you.

Like so

```
setState(() {
  if(day > 0 && day <=30) {
    _counter[day] = (prefs.getInt('counter$day') ?? 0);
    _score=_counter[day];
  }
});
```

As you can see, by using the $ sign in the string, you can substitute it for the value of `day`

Okay, with this done, what you can do is the following.

You don't need to get SharedPreferences instance every time you want to perform an action on it.

I would suggest you to store it in a variable that can be accessed from both functions.

For example, you can use a FutureBuilder:

```
...

FutureBuilder(
  future: () => _getSharedPrefInstance(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return YourWidgetHere();
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
);

...

Future<SharedPreferences> _getSharedPreferences() async {
  final instance = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  setState(() async {
    prefs= instance;
  });

  return instance;
}

...
```

So here, what we are doing is, utilizing the `FutureBuilder` widget. This will await for a Future, while it's waiting for the future to complete it will show a `CircularProgressIndicator`, then, when the future gets resolved, it will show the loaded widget `YourWidgetHere`.

We also `await` for the SharedPreferences in another function. This function will wait for the instance, and then save it in a variable, so that you can access it from your functions (`_loadDay` & `_incrementCounter`).

From those functions, you can then just call `prefs.getInt` & `prefs.setInt`.

This will improve the speed of your code.

Comment: It didnt worked.. Its saving the right amount but when I switch pages and get back to the main counter its shows '0' until I increase day und decrease it to that day... than its showing the right number..